# Making a very long number a string (aesthetics quest'n)

Tags: c++

I'm working on the project Euler problems, and #8 requires that you find the largest product of 5 consecutive numbers in a 1000-digit number.  Does anyone know how I can format the number to be one long string over multiple lines instead of having it be one long string on one line?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do what @Blastfurnace suggests, or you can just copy and paste this: http://pastebin.com/H3DRy678

Comment: I know this is somewhat off topic, but you don't even need code to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler will automatically concatenate string literals that are separated by white space. You can simply do:

```
const char bignum[] = 
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
    ... more lines here ...
    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
```

The resulting character array will be the same as if you typed one **very** long string literal. [A link for the lazy](http://pastebin.com/jd7iFsjp).

Answer (score 0):

There is a big number library for c++ in https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Comment: Missing the point: the input for the numerical part is the set of  substrings of 5 digits. That fits in a `long`.